# Did any dinosaur molt?

Tags: palaeontology

Like snakes or lizards, did any dinosaur molt ?

if yes, have we any proof of it ?

Comment: Since dinosaurs had either scales or feathers, and both [reptiles and birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Moulting&redirect=no) go through molting, then dinosaurs probably molted too. However, I doubt the skin came off in 1 piece like a snake, but came off in small parts. Since the skin probably wouldn't fossilize well, we probably have no way of confirming any of this.

Comment: Snakes and lizards are a different clade of reptiles altogether (they are Squamata i.e. scaled reptilse). Not all reptiles molt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Richard Prum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Prum) (the author of [Evolution of feathers](http://prumlab.yale.edu/sites/default/files/prum_1999_mde_development.pdf)) says that ornithology is mostly a science about dinosaurs. He insists that dinosaurs were very close to birds, part of them had feathers and these feathered dinosaurs "shed (molt) them as birds of our days do".

Thus, we can conclude that dinosaurs probably possessed at least one molting-like mechanism, while others are the subjects for consecutive investigations.

sources
[Moulting tail feathers in a juvenile oviraptorisaur](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v468/n7320/full/nature09480.html). Nature, 2010.